# Blazor Server Hosted - Configure OpenId Connect with AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-cognito, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to setup Blazor (server side - Preview 6) with AWS Cognito. Unfortunately, I don't have much experience with ASP.NET Core or OAuth/OpenId. It's currently at the point where I can click on the `OpenIdConnect` button and the user authenticates. But this is the result I see (once Cognito redirects to `https://localhost:44385/signin-oidc`):

[image]

So it's driving me nuts. What does "Error loading external login information" mean? Is it something to do with permissions/the allowed scope? I did try `options.Scope.Add()` with "email", "profile" and/or "openid" - but that didn't seem to help.

Here's what's in my `Startup.cs` file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>( options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")) );
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Cognito"));

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var authOptions = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>>();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
            options.MetadataAddress = authOptions.Value.MetadataAddress;
            options.ClientId = authOptions.Value.ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = authOptions.Value.ClientSecret;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            options.SaveTokens = authOptions.Value.SaveTokens;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = authOptions.Value.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer
            };
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
}
```

And here's the contents of the output window:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://localhost:44385/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F application/x-www-form-urlencoded 248
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint '/Account/ExternalLogin'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Route matched with {page = "/Account/ExternalLogin", area = "Identity"}. Executing page /Account/ExternalLogin
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executing handler method Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V4.Pages.Account.Internal.ExternalLoginModel.OnPost - ModelState is Invalid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executed handler method OnPost, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult: Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes (OpenIdConnect).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executed page /Account/ExternalLogin in 113.68560000000001ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint '/Account/ExternalLogin'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 302.9229ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44385/signin-oidc?code=ffbac0f8-e1e6-46fc-a64e-cd7ece7b4dd8&state=CfDJ8NccaQdck19Fie6EgKf0wAIZI23G5O9M52tXkPEptmR-6XW3ZWJQxlTYSHItlOdqzfZf7ZfscXMZg4Pew0gG0ybmyy_pOocBL--CC4j3deAsKtUM4bqUE7KyiKYqMpanwbCEShZBQZa1I32U-5F4jgHRS9Ott56PhEDAFgmOk6WmceSpCO058lYWQnVMtc1vUQ5M1_Shhv4y4jUJRYpVdVqsRqF5vVtQTvrMYlJlCsclALjQZmuEs_UO15Nq-7Q0VZhsypc4OmXGVVAfwL65uHMX1Q2JbVhb21unxcotUphXPEv5VYJBsqpq7qLA-9rl19XzOmJoq2SSx6g0N_AC-nmntuNVeUyIVh3OMTju8Qb6YJOMpE5p2zK0PgnpGxsA57kTH6laJbD_B-EIE2Bk_1rRCtczlmtaAx2wCnMwVsDM  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 644.9236000000001ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44385/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F&handler=Callback  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint '/Account/ExternalLogin'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Route matched with {page = "/Account/ExternalLogin", area = "Identity"}. Executing page /Account/ExternalLogin
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executing handler method Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V4.Pages.Account.Internal.ExternalLoginModel.OnGetCallbackAsync - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executed handler method OnGetCallbackAsync, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToPageResult.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult: Information: Executing RedirectToPageResult, redirecting to ./Login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executed page /Account/ExternalLogin in 11.1302ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint '/Account/ExternalLogin'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 30.221500000000002ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44385/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint '/Account/Login'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Route matched with {page = "/Account/Login", area = "Identity"}. Executing page /Account/Login
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executing handler method Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.V4.Pages.Account.Internal.LoginModel.OnGetAsync - ModelState is Valid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executed handler method OnGetAsync, returned result .
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executing an implicit handler method - ModelState is Invalid
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executed an implicit handler method, returned result Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.PageResult.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker: Information: Executed page /Account/Login in 42.6662ms
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executed endpoint '/Account/Login'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 157.9035ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44385/Identity/css/site.css  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44385/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Information: The file /Identity/css/site.css was not modified
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Information: The file /Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css was not modified
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 115.28320000000001ms 304 text/css
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 125.4239ms 304 text/css
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44385/Identity/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44385/Identity/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44385/Identity/js/site.js  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Information: The file /Identity/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js was not modified
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Information: The file /Identity/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js was not modified
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 109.1367ms 304 application/javascript
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 117.52770000000001ms 304 application/javascript
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Information: The file /Identity/js/site.js was not modified
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44385/Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 212.7227ms 304 application/javascript
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Information: The file /Identity/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js was not modified
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44385/Identity/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 169.02100000000002ms 304 application/javascript
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware: Information: The file /Identity/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js was not modified
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 146.98080000000002ms 304 application/javascript
```

There's no obvious error in there. Here's my Cognito config:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there something I'm missing. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

**Update**

If I click on the home page link, I can see that I **am** logged in. So there's something not right with the redirect after the callback from Cognito?

Comment: I've bypassed the error message for now by removing the call to `AddDefaultIdentity`. Which means I lose the login page. So now I'm trying to figure out how to trigger the Cognito procedure - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56964793/server-side-blazor-preview-6-is-it-possible-to-require-authentication-for-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the cause of the error message was from this configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
  options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options => { ... } );
```

Taking a hint from this [comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/695#issuecomment-171111237) on GitHub:

> The UseIdentity call is registering two cookie middlewares, one for the ApplicationCookie and one for the ExternalApplicationCookie. These are set to different authentication schemes by default. It should just work if you remove all of these explicit authentication scheme settings and rely on the default values...

I reduced it to this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
  .AddCookie()
  .AddOpenIdConnect(options => { ... } );
```

The error was happening with the call to `https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F&handler=Callback`. Because of the mis-configuration, it would throw the error, "Error loading external login information".

With the new configuration the login/logout now works as expected!

Comment: Hi @Mitkins, did you render your custom HTML for login page? or was it generic from the AWS?