# Server Side Blazor (Preview 6) - is it possible to require authentication for a particular page?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

For a Blazor server hosted page - is it possible to require authentication? Based on the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.0

I've added the following to my `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion( CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2 );

  services.AddAuthorization(options =>
  {
      options.AddPolicy("Private", policy => policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser() );
  });
}
```

And here's what I've put at the top of the `fetchdata` page:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@using HollyTest.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService
@attribute [Authorize(Policy="Private")]

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>
```

Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track?

Comment: Also, [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/security/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorize-attribute) implies that I can use Policies too. But `RequireAuthenticatedUser` isn't supported?